# Photoshop Scripting with Javascript: How to unlock a partially locked layer?

Tags: javascript, jsx, photoshop

I've tried many ways to unlock a partially locked layer in Photoshop using Javascript but nothing works. Here's a few examples of what I've tried:

```
var layerRef = app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName('Background');
layerRef.allLocked = false;
```

The below alert returns `false`:

```
alert(app.activeDocument.layers[0].allLocked);
```

So it's not locked? I just want to convert this partially locked layer to a not locked layer.

My documentation source:

https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2019.pdf

[image: partially locked layer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Background` is kind of a particular weird layer type in Photoshop. To unlock it (and convert to a normal layer) you need to use this specific command:

`activeDocument.activeLayer.isBackgroundLayer = false;`

Using the same property you can check if a layer is a `Background` layer and you can set any layer as a BG layer.